# Migrating from JUnit4 to JUnit5 throws NullPointerException on @Autowired repositories

Tags: maven, spring-boot, junit5

I have a very simple repository test, it runs just fine when I'm using 
JUnit's 4 "@RunWith(SpringRunner.Class)". When I tried to use "@ExtendWith" like in the provided example I get a NullPointerException when trying to work with the repository. It seems like "@Autowire" doesn't inject the repository when using the latter annotation. Here's the pom.xml file and stack trace: https://pastebin.com/4KSsgLfb

Entity Class:

```
package org.tim.entities;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Data
public class ExampleEntity {

@Id
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@NonNull
private String name;
```

}

Repository Class:

```
package org.tim.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.tim.entities.ExampleEntity;

@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<ExampleEntity, Long> {
}
```

Test Class:

```
package org.tim;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.tim.entities.ExampleEntity;
import org.tim.repositories.ExampleRepository;


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class exampleTestClass {

@Autowired
private ExampleRepository exampleRepository;

@Test
public void exampleTest() {
    exampleRepository.save(new ExampleEntity("name"));
}
}
```

Comment: what does your pom.xml look like, what junit5 dependencies have you pulled in?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I've added fragment of pom.xml file.

Comment: Can you please make a _Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_ available? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SamBrannen I've added missing classes, hope that's an appropriate example

Comment: Yep, that's what I wanted to see. You're using the wrong `@Test` annotation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using the wrong `@Test` annotation.

When using the `SpringExtension` and JUnit Jupiter (JUnit 5), you have to use `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` instead of `import org.junit.Test;`.

Comment: nice catch Sam!

Answer (score 1):

in the documentation it says:

> If you are using JUnit 4, don’t forget to also add @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) to your test, otherwise the annotations will be ignored. If you are using JUnit 5, there’s no need to add the equivalent @ExtendWith(SpringExtension) as @SpringBootTest and the other @…Test annotations are already annotated with it.

[Testing Spring Boot Applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)

So try removing the @extendWith in your testclass

Comment: I've tried removing it and changing "@DataJpaTest" to "@SpringBootTest", didn't work.